# Create two ios developer accounts

Tags: iphone, ios

I was wondering is there any way to create 2 ios developer accounts with same bank account ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sire it is simply not possible to create two developer ACCOUNTS, for the same person.  (Or, the same company.)

So, the "bank account" part isn't the problem. **The problem is you simply can't create two accounts for the same person (or company)** ... as far as I know.

---

I guess the problem you're having: *you want to separate the accounting for two different products.**  That is a huge nuisance even for the largest companies. There's no easy solution.

*A word of advice if you're just starting out: it's almost inconceivable you'll make any real money from apps. If you're ever making serious money from not one but two apps, deal with the problem then.*

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that I've made >$50 with my app, "HughesNet Status Meter", and I'm certainly not in the top 1500 apps (although I wish). Curious: what's the $18 point?

Comment: No, I was just saying that I've made more than 18 dollars and am ranked below #1,500. :P I was curious why you specifically mentioned $18.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate a new LLC that you own, and have that company enroll as an iOS Developer under the company's name.

Comment: IANAL.  But I have read reports of developers in the U.S. with both an individual iOS developer account, as well as separate company account(s) for their LLC and/or S-Corp corporation(s).  As usual, check with an attorney (and maybe a tax accountant) in your legal jurisdiction for the legalities involved.